# how to find if a given string conforms to hex notation, eg. 0x34FF without regex?

Tags: c++, string, pattern-matching

In regex it would be `0x[0-9a-fA-F]+`, but how to achieve it in pure c++ ?

Comment: Have you considered using a loop?

Comment: See here for a solution (convert to hex and check if succeeded): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594045/converting-a-string-with-a-hexadecimal-value-to-an-actual-hexadecimal-value

Comment: Although in this instance it's quite simple, as soon as you try to write either regular expression replacements for non-ASCII strings, or replacements with more complex search strings it gets messy. I hope you're not prematurely optimizing.

Comment: Are you aware of the changes in the new C++ standard? Pure C++ *includes* regular expressions now.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the built-in methods of `std::string` to check that the first portion of the string is the literal "0x" and that the remainder of the string contains only the allowed characters. Here is the equivalent to the regular expression given in the question:

```
bool is_hex_notation(std::string const& s)
{
  return s.compare(0, 2, "0x") == 0
      && s.size() > 2
      && s.find_first_not_of("0123456789abcdefABCDEF", 2) == std::string::npos;
}
```

Comment: Although the OP didn't reflect this in his regular expression, `"0X1a"` is also a legal hex value.

Answer (score 7):

With C++11 you can do it easily:

```
std::string str = "FF22ABCD16ZZ";

if (std::all_of(str.begin(), str.end(), ::isxdigit)) {
    std::cout << str << " contains only hexadecimal digits" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: That's nice, I like it. However, this [page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isxdigit) says that a cast is required: `[](unsigned char c){ return std::isxdigit(c); }`

Answer (score 3):

Call [`strtoul`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoul) and check for an error.

Comment: That's probably the best solution.  (Of the two others already posted, one is total spaghetti, and formally incorrect, and the other contains a subtle error.  So anything you write yourself is going to be non-trivial.)

Comment: @James, the other answer only contains an error if the *question* also contains the same error. If you happen to know that whatever syntax rsk82 is checking also allows uppercase "X" in its hexadecimal notation, then please correct the question, and then one of us can correct the answer, too. (If the error you refer to is something else, then it's too subtle for me to notice, so please just correct it yourself.)

Comment: I don't understand how to check for error with strtoul. It looks like strtoul(str, NULL, 16) returns the hex value regardless of whether str has a leading "0x " or not.

Comment: Do not pass 0 as the second arg.

Comment: Using **strtoul** on 4MB Hex file gave me this error : **Error : : Result too large
Error : errno : 34** this method fails if hex-string is too large.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
bool IsHex(const std::string& str) {
  if (str.length < 3 || str[0] != '0') {
    return false;
  }

  if (str[1] != 'x' && str[1] != 'X') {    
    return false;
  }

  for (size_t i = 2; i < str.length; i++) {
    char current = str[i];
    if (current >= '0' && current <= '9') {
      continue;
    }

    if (current >= 'A' && current <= 'F') {
      continue;
    }

    if (current >= 'a' && current <= 'f') {
      continue;
    }

    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: It seems to works, but this function is really slow.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this instead **strspn** to check for valid base.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strspn/

**example below in C++ this method checks for any radix valid base from 
binary-to-base32**

```
/* strspn valid-number example */

#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cstring>

#define BINARY_BASE 2 /*Defining binary base*/
#define OCTAL_BASE 8  /*Defining octal base*/
#define DECIMAL_BASE 10 /*Defining decimal base*/
#define HEXA_BASE 16    /*Defining hexa-decimal base*/
#define BASE32_BASE 32 /*Defining base32 base*/

bool isValidNumber4Base(const char* numStr,int base)
{

    const char *validBinary = "01";
    const char *validOctal = "01234567";
    const char *validDecimal = "0123456789";
    const char *validHex = "0123456789abcdefxABCDEFX";
    const char *validBase32 = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV";
    const char *validNumber = NULL;

    validNumber = (base == BINARY_BASE) ? validBinary : ((base == OCTAL_BASE) ? validOctal :
                    (base == DECIMAL_BASE) ? validDecimal : (base == HEXA_BASE) ? validHex : (base == BASE32_BASE) ? validBase32 : NULL);

    if(validNumber ==  NULL)
    {
        std::cerr<<"Invalid base encountered"<<std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return (!numStr[strspn(numStr,validNumber)]) ? true : false;
}

/*Test Method */
int main ()
{
  char *hexa_str = "0xFF";  
  std::cout<<"Valid Hexa : "<<std::boolalpha<<isValidNumber4Base(hexa_str,HEXA_BASE)<<std::endl;        
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `std::count_if` to check if the count equals the size.

```cpp
std::string_view v("0xa3");

bool correctPrefix = v.rfind("0x", 0) == 0 && v.length() > 2;
correctPrefix = correctPrefix ? std::count_if(v.begin() + 2,
                         v.end(),
                         ::isxdigit) == v.length() - 2 : false;
```